# converting angle to radian

Tags: c++, math

I got angle in degree as -415 degrees,

i have converted it into radian as

```
float degreeValue = -415

float radianValue = degreeValue * pi / 180.0;
```

here i got as -0.7(round off)

how to convert again into degree to get same value of angle in degrees.

Comment: Pretty sure you could have figure this out yourself

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about high school math, not programming.

Answer (score 11):

```
float degreeValue = radianValue * 180.0 / pi;
```

(and you probably meant -7.24 radian and not -0.7 for -415 degrees)

Comment: +1 for taking hte time to explain this.

Comment: I would guess OP meant -41.5 degrees, given one usually uses the range (-180,180]